# Inspect Element of Chrome within and Android Studio virtual device

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-studio, mobile

I have a local app running in an Android Studio Virtual Device (Nexus 5X), as below:

[image]

Is there any way I can `Inspect Element` using Chrome, as I can do in the browser?